# How can I write data into an excel using PHP?

Tags: php, export-to-excel

Is it possible to append content to an .xls file using PHP `fwrite()`?

When I try this using `fwrite()`, the resulting file causes an error message in Excel 2007.

Is there a specific separator I can use to accomplish this?

Is it possible without a third party library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for PHP_excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) - though the question is not the same, the list in there will answer your question.

Comment: What format is your Excel file? Is it a CSV file, a BIFF5 or 8 .xls file, or an MS Office OpenXML .xlsx file?

Comment: @Gordon . Read the question Mr. I have an excel already.i want to write into that excel using fwrite without classes. . Some guys are here to just down vote . They cant give answers. FTW

Comment: I did not downvote. I did read the question. I gave 1393 answers up to now. I already agreed the one I closevoted with is not exactly what you asked for. Still, there is plenty other [questions about how to append to an excel file](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=append+excel+file+php). Unfortunately, you fail to mention what the file format of your Excel file is (like Mark Baker already pointed out), so it's hard to find a proper duplicate. IMO, you are better off using "excel classes".

Comment: i ask this on october last year 2010. i got one downvote that month .thats ok . and i accept an answer too. Today i got a downvote(Jul 2011) .Nasty

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) library, to read an existing Excel file, add new rows/columns to it, then write it back as a real Excel file.

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of this library.

Comment: Thanks . As you are the other  can i ask you something.How wil be performance if i write more than 65000 records. Is there any option to add another sheet when it reaches the excel max limit 65536 rows?

Comment: @MarkBaker : is it possible to write into new excel using your lib

Comment: @Hitesh - perfectly possible to create an Excel spreadsheet using PHPExcel

Comment: @Hitesh - If you are having problems, then "ask a question" (this is a Q&A board, not a forum), don't simply comment on the answer to a different question; and if you're getting errors then tell what you're doing (showing code where appropriate) and what errors you're getting.

Comment: Somebody anonymous has just tried to edit this answer to ask another question.... that's not the way things work on StackOverflow

Comment: In answer to that question: PHPExcel loads data from file into memory, and is constrained by PHP's memory limitations, but there are methods in PHPExcel (such as cell caching) to reduce the memory required when working with large files (although at a cost in execution speed). These are documented, so I'd suggest reading the documentation

Comment: @MarkBaker The link on this is broken :(

Comment: @JeffDavis - It' a pretty old link, on a pretty old answer.... we've been on github for nearly 5 years now... I've updated the answer with the [github link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Answer (score 6):

You can try and create a CSV file, like this:

```
name;surname;blabla
name;surname;blabla
name;surname;blabla
name;surname;blabla
```

Excel should eat this :)

It is convenient to use PHP CVS functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 1):

to write you can use : Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer is a tool for creating Excel files without the need for COM components

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.php
but you cant appaend to file , only to create it.

or using phpexcel (support excel 2007)

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

and you can append see a example :

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=82996

Comment: The Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer is currently unmaintained (last release 2012-01-26). Also causes error "File Error: data may have been lost." [Bug #12848  Excel "File Error: data may have been lost."](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=12848)
[WARNING: Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and Office Service Pack 3](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/spreadsheet-writeexcel/Pc6kDmYgrzo)

Answer (score 1):

use from **fputcsv** function
for example :

```
 $data[] = array("item 1", "item 1");
    $export = fopen("file.csv", "w");
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($export, $row, "\t");
    }
    fclose($export);
```

for more example : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

if you just want/need to create a very simple table, you just need to make a [*.csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)-file which can be opened by excel - but not: you can't use formulas in this and you can't do any kind of formatting.

Comment: Actually, you can use formulas in a CSV file, though you have to take more care that the formula references the correct rows and columns: R1C1 format is often easier to use than A1 format addressing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this library 
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

or you can create .csv file for example and then import them to excel.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple library for exporting Excel-friendly XML files from PHP: http://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data

Comment: the OP asks for XLS and the class you suggest export CSVs