# fwrite($fp,$schema_insert) not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to fetch my data from DB and download xls file but it not writing my actual data into the sheet. I think it doesn't work. Should I add something more to my code?

```
 <?php 
include 'functions.php';
 ob_start();

?>
<?php
if($_POST['types'] == 'name') {  

    $query = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE name='".$_POST['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC ";  
}  
elseif($_POST['types'] == 'mobile') {  

    $query = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE mobile='".$_POST['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC ";  
} 
elseif($_POST['types'] == 'OccasionType') {  

    $query = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE OccasionType='".$_POST['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC ";  
} 

elseif($_POST['types'] == 'InquiryDate') {  
    $query="SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE TodayDate between '".$_POST['From']."' and '".$_POST['TO']."' ORDER BY id DESC " ;  
}

 elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'OccasionDate') {  
    $query="SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE date between '".$_POST['From']."' and '".$_POST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC ";  
                            }
else {  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail ORDER BY id DESC ";  
    } 

$result = mysql_query($query); 

$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character 
$fp = fopen('database.xls', "w"); 
$schema_insert = ""; 
$schema_insert_rows = ""; 
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields

//start of adding column names as names of MySQL fields 
for ($i = 1; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) 
{ 
$schema_insert_rows.=mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t"; 
} 
$schema_insert_rows.="\n"; 
echo $schema_insert_rows; 
fwrite($fp, $schema_insert_rows); 
//end of adding column names

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$schema_insert = ""; 
for($j=1; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++) 
{ 
if(!isset($row[$j])) 
$schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep; 
elseif ($row[$j] != "") 
$schema_insert .= strip_tags("$row[$j]").$sep;
else 
$schema_insert .= "".$sep; 
} 
$schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert); 

//this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r 
//these two characters are now replaced with a space 

$schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert); 
$schema_insert .= "\n"; 
//$schema_insert = (trim($schema_insert)); 
//print $schema_insert .= "\n"; 
//print "\n";

fwrite($fp,$schema_insert); }

fclose($fp);

header('Content-Type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my.xls');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

?>
```

Comment: You're writing to a file, but not doing anything with that file. Simply writing a file on the server doesn't automagically display that file to the client browser

Comment: @MarK Baker  then what should i do to fetch data...in to the correct formate???

Comment: Well an obvious answer would be to readfile() your 'database.xls' file after you've sent the headers; but there's a flaw here if two clients both request a download at the same time

Comment: Check this one:

[how can i write data into an excel using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968973/how-can-i-write-data-into-an-excel-using-php)

Comment: Either use a tempfile that's unique to each request - http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php may help - so that each request isn't overwriting the other's data

Comment: Or why use a file in the first place? Why not simply send each line of the output directly to the client's browser (send headers first); especially as you're not using fputcsv() or anything like that which would make your life easier... and even  if you were, you could write to php://output rather than a disk file

Comment: You also need to fclose($fp); after first fwrite as well.

Comment: @Mark Baker..yes you were right...i add readfile() and its working correctly

Answer (score 1):

Two misconceptions:

1. Perhaps the feature is called "Download an Excel file" but that doesn't imply that you have to create a real file.
2. PHP does not magically send to the browser all the files you create server-side.

Get rid of all the file related code and simply change this:

```
fwrite($fp,$schema_insert);
```

... into this:

```
echo $schema_insert;
```

Also, move these lines before the first `echo`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my.xls');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

**Edit:** Despite the several mentions to XLS format, code in question basically creates a CSV file and sends it with fake HTTP headers to trick Excel into opening it. As Mark points out, PHP has a [builtin function to create CSV files](http://php.net/fputcsv) so you don't have to write the code yourself. This function expects a file pointer but, again, [there's no need to actually create a file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#104980): you can call [fopen()](http://php.net/fopen) with `php://output` as file name and everything will be sent to the browser automatically.

Comment: And don't forget it's worth defining php://output as the filename rather than database.xls, for those cases where multiple requests are being made concurrently

Comment: @MarkBaker - I think you misread my answer. What I basically say is that there doesn't need to be a file at all.

Comment: True, my mistake - although using a filename of php://output can allow OP to use fputcsv() instead of "rolling his own"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server can not allow you write the file. You can only query the data from database and format it to tables, and use header function to download it.

Comment: Can you bother providing download code along with this story?

Comment: You can use 'echo' function to form a table, and after this, use `code`header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: filename=test.xls');

Comment: no  actually it allows me to write in to the file ...because firsr fwrite() works ..thats why i am getting column name..but the second fwrite() not working actually...i dnt knw why

Comment: @DeadMan Thank you, i am a fresh.