# script to extract from a website and create list of words in excel

Tags: php, database, excel, web-scraping

I want to cross list allrecordlabels.com by US state (Alabama, California, New York Mississipi Tennessee, North, South Carolina and Georgia) and genre as following :

A1 LABEL NAME / B1 STATE NAME / C1 MUSICAL GENRE(S) ( and if you know how to add : D1 contact email of the label you can find on the page of some labels) Then make an alphabetical list by collumn.

If there is several genres for a label you can stack them in the same column.

Here some code we worked on :

```
 <?php

 $labelsData = array();

 $stateListPage = file_get_contents('http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/');



 preg_match_all('#<li> <a href="([A-Z]+)\.html">([a-zA-Z ]+)</a></li>#', 
 $stateListPage, 
 $statePagesURL);



 foreach($statePagesURL[1] AS $statePageURL) {
 $statePage = file_get_contents('http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/' . 
 $statePageURL . '.html');


 preg_match('#<h2>State ([a-zA-Z ]+)</h2>#', $statePage, $state);
 $state = $state[1];

 preg_match_all('#<li><a href="https?://.+\.[a-z]{2,5}">([^<]+)</a>#',     

 $statePage,     $labelsFound);

 foreach($labelsFound[1] AS $label) {
 if(!isset($labelsData[$label]))
    $labelsData[$label] = array('state' => $state);
 else
    $labelsData[$label]['state'] .= ' - ' . $state;
 }
 }
 /*
 $genreListPage = file_get_contents('http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/genres/');
 preg_match_all('#<li> <a href="([^\.]).html">([a-zA-Z /-]+)</a></li>#',     

 $genreListPage, $genrePagesURL);
 print_r($labelsData);*/

?>
```

All of these informations are listed and easily accesible on the website. Can you help me to make this script working, how do i transfert in excel btw?

Thanks

labels by genre : http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/genres/

states http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/

labels by state:

Alabama http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/AL.html

Mississipi http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/MS.html

Tennessee http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/TN.html

North Carolina http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/NC.html

South Carolina http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/SC.html

Georgia http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/GA.html

New york http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/NY.html

California http://www.allrecordlabels.com/db/state/CA.html

Comment: Take at look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968973/how-can-i-write-data-into-an-excel-using-php