# i want to write array in excel sheet(xlx) using php

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I want to write an array into an Excel sheet: Can someone help me? How can I write this array in excel sheet?

My array:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => age
        [2] => name
        [3] => gender
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 12
        [2] => alexander
        [3] => male

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [1] => 18
        [2] => shine
        [3] => female
    )

)
```

I want this output:

[image]

I want to write this array in excel sheet and, after writing the array, to download file as an Excel spreadsheet (xlsx).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968973/how-can-i-write-data-into-an-excel-using-php

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can store the array as csv file or use the one of Excel php library to create the excel file you can check this library :
[PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this code on my dev server and it should work perfectly:

1. Get the [PHPExcel library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) and put it on your server.
2. Use this code:

   ```
   // Include the PHPExcel libraries
   require_once "PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php"; // Or whatver the path to your PHPExcel library is
   require_once "PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";

   // Set up your input data array
   $data = array(
       array("age", "name", "gender"),
       array("12", "alexander", "male"),
       array("18", "shine", "female"),
   );

   // Create the PHPExcel object
   $xl = new PHPExcel();

   // Write the data into the new spreadsheet starting at cell A1
   $xl->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data, NULL, 'A1');

   // Create a spreadsheet writer, in this case for Excel 2007 (xlsx)
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xl, 'Excel2007');

   // Set the appropriate headers for the download:
   header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

   // Name the file
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export.xlsx");
   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   // We're finished!
   die;
   ```

Alternately, if you want to do something different with the file you've just generated, you can replace everything after `$objWriter` with something like this:

```
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$fileContents = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

I understanding that you want to generate .XLS file. right?
The Following code will do.

```
require_once "PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php"; //the path to your PHPExcel library 
require_once "PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";

    // Set up your input data array
    $data = array(
        array("age", "name", "gender"),
        array("12", "alexander", "male"),
        array("18", "shine", "female"),
    );
$name ="sheet name";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWriter  = array();
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();            
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($name);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\""filename.xls");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
ob_get_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
ob_end_flush();
exit;
```