# Inserting data into Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I need to take data entered into MySQL database, open an existing Excel workbook, enter data in specific cells, then rename the workbook and save it.

I am not looking for freebie answers, I just need to know if it's possible and if so could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Take a look at [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

Comment: Thank you sevavietl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i write data into an excel using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968973/how-can-i-write-data-into-an-excel-using-php)