# Php export to excel some data

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I have information that I want to display in a excel scheet. I don't want to just plainly print the data as it is in the database. I want to control the formatting, but I can't get it to display the information right.

My code is :

```
$rep_disp = new new_report($db_link);
$rep_disp->export_summary_report_to_csv();
$out = '';
$i = 1;
foreach($rep_disp->inc_inc_t_list as $inc_t)
{
    $inc_current = '';
    $inc_current = reset($rep_disp->inc_t_curr_list[$inc_t]);
    $inc_t_amo = $rep_disp->inc_t_amo_tot[$inc_t][$inc_current];
    $out.= ','.$rep_disp->disp_inc_t_name($inc_t).',"","","","","'.$inc_t_amo.'","'.$rep_disp->disp_curr_name($inc_current).'",';
    foreach($rep_disp->inc_loc_list[$inc_t] as $inc_loc)
    {
        $k = 0;
        $out.= '\n,"","","'.$rep_disp->disp_loc_name($inc_loc).'",';

        foreach ($rep_disp->inc_cur_list[$inc_t][$inc_loc] as $inc_curr)
        {                                                                       
            /*emptying the variable to ensure a new information on each line or no display if there's none*/
            $inc_t_amo = '';
            $inc_current = '';/*this is the current currency that we are working on. It's independent from the foreach loop we use for the currency*/
            $inc_var_test = next($rep_disp->inc_t_curr_list[$inc_t]);/*will use to check if there's information to show*/
            if($inc_var_test <> '' and isset($rep_disp->inc_t_amo_tot[$inc_t][$inc_var_test]))
            {
                $inc_t_amo = $rep_disp->inc_t_amo_tot[$inc_t][$inc_var_test];
                $inc_current = $rep_disp->disp_curr_name($inc_var_test);
            }
            if($k == 0)
            {
                $out.='"'.$rep_disp->inc_loc_tot_list[$inc_t][$inc_loc][$inc_curr].'","'.$rep_disp->disp_curr_name($inc_curr).'","","'.$inc_t_amo.'","'.$inc_current.'",\n';
            }
                elseif($k > 0)
                {
                    $out.= '\n,"","","","'.$rep_disp->inc_loc_tot_list[$inc_t][$inc_loc][$inc_curr].'","'.$rep_disp->disp_curr_name($inc_curr).'","","'.$inc_t_amo.'","'.$inc_current.'",\n';
                }
            $k++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be willing to consider exporting the data as a CSV and doing  a manual import in excel to complete the formatting? PHP has some pretty handy functions for that if you dont want to manually write file writing code.

Comment: Your code is describing writing a CSV, but your question is about exporting an Excel file for formatting. These are very different things; take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005814/export-from-php-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

I use http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer, although it looks like it's no longer maintained.