# Export data from php to excel

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export from PHP to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005814/export-from-php-to-excel)

I need to export data retrieved from mysql database to excel. I need to do some changes to my data before exporting to excel. I really can't understand how I should begin.

Should i go for PEAR? or any other class library? or any simple way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export from PHP to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005814/export-from-php-to-excel) … and many other questions here on SO; see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library. It allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats.

Comment: To enhance the answer please refer to this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005814/export-from-php-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

You may go through **[How to Generate a Complete Excel Spreadsheet From MySQL](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-generate-a-complete-excel-spreadsheet-from-mysql/)** and **[Read and write Excel data with PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/)**.

Hope this helps.