# PHP export excel with checkbox

Tags: php, excel, forms, checkbox, export

I want to export an excel file with checkbox like the picture below but i don't know how to do it. Please help me!
PHPExcel is not support for checkbox.

Thanks so much!
[Click here to view attach file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AItTZ.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, we're not a free guide / tutorial service, we appreciate people showing us what they have tried and show that they've done some research, I'd strongly recommend that you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you can get a better idea of how SO works and how to write your question in order to get the best answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export from PHP to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005814/export-from-php-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Then you have three alternative choices

- PHP's [COM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) (requires a COM enabled spreadsheet program such as MS Excel or OpenOffice Calc running on the server)
- The Open Office alternative to COM ([PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)) (requires Open Office installed on the server with Java support enabled)
- Ilia Alshanetsky's [Excel extension](http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html) now on [github](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel) (requires the commercial [libXL](http://www.libxl.com/) component)