# how to fix encoding from a iso8859-1 php generated file to excel program

Tags: php, excel, encoding

I'm creating an excel file downloadable from a web page with this piece of code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

$ressource_sql = execute_sql($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ressource_sql)) {


    $ligne_hve.=$row['id'] . ';';
    $ligne_hve.=$row['name'] . ';';
    $ligne_hve.=$row['products'] . ';';    
    $ligne_hve .= "\n";

}
$file_hve = fopen($file_export_hve, "w+");
fwrite($file_hve, $ligne_hve);
fclose($file_hve);
```

The Excel file is regenerated each time the user consult the web page with this code, all the website is ISO8859-1,i know excel is using a strange encoding (windows-1252) but for now i didn' t find any tricks to get the french accent (well displayed on the website) into the excel...

Thx for help

Comment: why not use a CSV file instead of excel? The CSV file can be opened by excel, and supports UTF-8 (which easily can handle your french accents)

Comment: @Nayena - looking at this code, krifur __is__ creating a separated value file (using ; rather than , as a separator); __not__ an Excel file

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually generating an Excel file. Your script generates a CSV file using semicolons. For a proper solution you should look into [PHPExcel or another library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel/3931142#3931142).

But your simple CSV output can be converted into UTF-8 nevertheless. It's advisable to add a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) so Excel detects it when it's sent with the wrong Content-Type:

```
file_put_contents("converted.csv", 
    "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . utf8_encode(file_get_contents("iso8859-1.csv"))
);
```

The `utf8_encode()` may or may not be required there. You didn't show any concrete example. If the text was already in UTF-8, then the BOM workaround already suffices and a second utf8_encode is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

$ressource_sql = execute_sql($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ressource_sql)) {


    $ligne_hve.=$row['id'] . ';';
    $ligne_hve.= iconv(input charset, 'windows-1252//TRANSLIT', $row['name']) . ';';
    $ligne_hve.= iconv(input charset, 'windows-1252//TRANSLIT', $row['products']) . ';';    
    $ligne_hve .= "\n";

}
$file_hve = fopen($file_export_hve, "w+");
fwrite($file_hve, $ligne_hve);
fclose($file_hve);
```

The input charset is iso-8859-1.