# Looking for a PHP to Excel library

Tags: php, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative for PHP_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel)

I'm looking for a lightweight and fast PHP Excel writer. I need to export Excel files up to 50000 rows. I've tried PHPExcel, but it is far too slow and memory-intensive.

It's only data, so formatting is not necessary.

Another requirement is that fields are often bigger than 255 characters. A lot of solutions I found don't support this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not export to CSV? It supports fields bigger than 255 characters and you can open if with Excel. Or OpenOffice.org. Or gnumeric. Or vi.

Comment: Do you need to open it in excel or just dump the data?

Comment: My non-technical clients need to open, modify and save the files in Excel.

Answer (score 4):

You could try these projects:

http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ (Excel 2007)

Comment: Quoting the OP: "I've tried PHPExcel"

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/ writes XML files, and I'd like 'real' Excel files.

Comment: @Henk de Slager: Since Excel 2007, the XML files are the real Excel files.  BIFF format has been legacy for four years now.  A modern piece of code should import/export in the [OPC-based Office Open XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats).