# Which is the best library to parse Excel files in PHP?

Tags: php, file-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative for PHP_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel)

I've found a number of PHP libraries for reading and parsing Excel files, such as [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and [PHP-Excel-Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/). Are there any other ones, and which is the best (i.e. the most robust, most update-to-date, etc.)?

Comment: I never found the available readers were much good for the modern OPC style files, so wrote my own when facing the problem.  Written for employer though, so can't release the code. :-/  It's just a set of XML files in a Zip, easy enough to read.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Definition of which is the best is very subjective... I have a vested interest when I say that [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) is the best, because I'm the main developer. However:

- very few of the packages listed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel/3931142#3931142) are still actively supported
- work only with one or other format of Excel files (BIFF .xls or Office Open XML .xlsx)
- can only read, or only write
- or require third-party plug-ins, or specific operating platforms

Best is a very subjective term, and it really depends on your exact requirements including

- whether you are able to use (for example) COM to interact directly with MS Excel on the server
- or need to both read and write Excel
- or need to work with xls, or xlsx or both formats
- or care about ongoing development/support