# PHPExcel Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'am trying to read xlsx file, but I get this error:

```
Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in E:\wamp\www\test\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 323
```

what this error mean?

Comment: And your complete code is?

Comment: can you unzip the archive with other tools?

Comment: Do you have php_zip enabled? What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and it was due to improper permissions.  Try doing a simple `fopen()` to make 100% sure you can read that file from the given directory.  Also, make sure you can read that file successfully if it's in the same directory as your script so you know the file itself is okay.

Comment: I have the same error, but the permissions does not seem to be the issue for me. The file can be opened and read.  Any other possible solutions?