# Laravel Excel, file import throws "ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object"

Tags: laravel-5, import, php-7.1, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using [Laravel excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) to import headers & some records.

With [this approach](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html#importing-only-the-heading-row), I should able to get headers:

```
$headings = (new HeadingRowImport)->toArray($myFile);
```

If `$myFile` is a CSV, it's OK; but if I tried with XLS or XLSX (with valid Mimetypes: `application/vnd.ms-excel` and `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, I'm getting such issue:

```
ZipArchive::getFromName(): 
Invalid or uninitialized Zip object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): 
ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object at 
/var/www/app/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php:308)

[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'ZipArchive::get...', '/var/www/app/ve...', 308, Array)
#1 /var/www/app/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php(308): ZipArchive->getFromName('_rels/.rels', 0, 1)
#2 /var/www/app/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php(2019): PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Reader\\Xlsx->getFromZipArchive(Object(ZipArchive), '_rels/.rels')
#3 /var/www/app/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php(343): PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Reader\\Xlsx->getWorkbookBaseName(Object(ZipArchive))
#4 /var/www/app/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Reader.php(229): PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Reader\\Xlsx->load('/tmp/laravel-ex...')
#5 /var/www/app/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Reader.php(215): Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Reader->readSpreadsheet()
```

I have tried to find related bugs but I only found PhpExcel, or PhpSpreadsheet, eg:

- [Read Xlsx file in PhpSpreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823233/read-xlsx-file-in-phpspreadsheet)
- [Why am I getting an "invalid or unitialized Zip object" error when trying to read excel file via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229346/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-or-unitialized-zip-object-error-when-trying-to-rea/29800597)
- [PHPExcel Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302772/phpexcel-warning-ziparchivegetfromname-invalid-or-unitialized-zip-object-i)
- [report bug on PhpSpreadsheet repo > read xlsx using filesystem gaufrette](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/447)

And I cannot find useful fix from them. Did anyone faced this issue, and how did you fix it ?

My package versions:

- "php": "^7.1.3",
- "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
- "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",

Note that my file has `read` permission as it is `644`, and I can open the file with `fopen($myFile, 'r')`

Answer (score 0):

Seemed like they have made some updates and the version `3.1.19` fixed the issue.