# PHPExcel - Severe performance slowdown when applying number formats

Tags: php, symfony, reporting, phpexcel

I've profiled my Excel generation code with xdebug and reviewed the grind file. Apparently the majority of my execution time is spent in:

```
setFormatCode(...)
```

[image]

And the offending code is here:

```
protected function formatRow($line)
{
    // /*
    foreach ($this->getIntegerColumns() as $column) {
        $style = $this->worksheet->getStyle($column . $line);
        $style->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0');
    }
    foreach ($this->getFloatColumns() as $column) {
        $style = $this->worksheet->getStyle($column . $line);
        $style->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    }
    foreach ($this->getPercentageColumns() as $column) {
        $style = $this->worksheet->getStyle($column . $line);
        $style->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00%');
    }
    foreach ($this->getDateColumns() as $column) {
        $style = $this->worksheet->getStyle($column . $line);
        $style->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('mm/dd/yyyy');
    }
    // */
    return $this;
}
```

My reports typically take:

```
getSummaryData: Elapsed time: 4
getInteractionData: Elapsed time: 10
getVideoData: Elapsed time: 2
new CampaignDetailReport: Elapsed time: 0
new CampaignDetailReportWriter: Elapsed time: 0
new write(): Elapsed time: 125

~ 140 seconds
```

But if I comment out the guts of the formatRow() function, it takes:

```
getSummaryData: Elapsed time: 4
getInteractionData: Elapsed time: 9
getVideoData: Elapsed time: 2
new CampaignDetailReport: Elapsed time: 0
new CampaignDetailReportWriter: Elapsed time: 0
new write(): Elapsed time: 32

~ 50 seconds
```

Which is still long, but a substantial improvement (nearly 50% faster).

I've reviewed the answer here: [PHPExcel very slow - ways to improve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983845/phpexcel-very-slow-ways-to-improve), but I'm not sure how to implement the fixes. Ideally, I think one solution would be to apply the style to the entire column, not on a cell-by-cell basis. If the column is something like 'cost', I know all the column values will be a float, so it's probably safe to apply the number format to all the cells. Just now sure how to actually do that.

UPDATE:

In response to Mark Bakers answer, I did the following:

```
foreach($this->getIntegerColumns() as $column) {
        $this->worksheet->getStyle(sprintf("%s%s:%s%s", $column, 5, $column, $this->line))
             ->getNumberFormat()
             ->setFormatCode('#,##0');
    }
```

Which styles all the columns of type integer for all the cells within the column. All my report metrics start at 5 and goto this->line, which is internal counter. This is working well so far. It took about 4 additional seconds to completely style one sheet (I have 3x sheets in my report). So at that rate I should be able to style all sheets and only incur an additional ~12 seconds of execution time, taking it to ~65 vs ~125 !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take advantage of the fluent interface.

Apply your formats to a range of cells where possible:

```
$this->worksheet->getStyle('A1:A21')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0.00%');
```

Use the style's applyFromArray() if you want to apply several style settings to a cell (or range of cells) in one go.

All of those techniques will help improve speed.

Comment: Great - I moved my formatting code a bit higher up in my class hierarchy and performed what you suggested. Working a lot better so far - have to update all my "sheets" to use this. Thanks. Updated my answer as well w/the actual code.

Comment: I seem to recall a planned feature to implement as follows:  $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($columnIndex)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('$#,##0.00');  Did this not happen?

Comment: No, row and column styles are not yet available