# Easy way to generate excel file for report with php

Tags: php, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative for PHP_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel)

i need a simple php library for generating excel file like PHPEXCEL library. i like PHPEXCEL library but it is heavy weight.

i need to  generate my report data in excel that  also display as html table. i need to convert htnl table data to excel without css.

i need to write in every cell.

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSV files? Excel can open them.