# Lightweight Excel(xls/xlsx) php library needed

Tags: php, excel, xls, xlsx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative for PHP_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel)

A friend would like to use a Php Excel library to read/write files on formats xls and xlsx, he knows about the one called "PhpExcel" but apparently is way too big of a library for him.

I would like you to suggest if there is any other phplib you could recommend him.

**Update**

Please people vote this question up if you think this post is useful even when some have considered it not good enough to give it negative points (very strange since it has a lot of views and seems it has actually helped to some users). Thank you very much.

Comment: We know it Zulk, but he is on an urge and wanted to try straight to the point help and it worked =)

Comment: Thanks for the post Gordon, gonna check the alternatives listed there.

Comment: in a side not: the PHPExcel Library is much lighter (in bytes) if  you remove PHPExcel/PDF/ , which is safe unless you use the PDF generators

Comment: Thanks jonathan, lets see how light it gets after removing what you suggest. Have a good day!.

Comment: Just found https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter it appears to have 90% less memory usage than phpexcel from some of my basic performance tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading only: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/ 21.5kb
Create your own very simply: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/

Comment: Thanks a lot Nur, we gonna check them out and let you know!

Comment: Create your own very simply => link is not working

Answer (score 2):

You won't find a lightweight library that can both read and write both xls and xlsx files other than PHPExcel. However, if you want a list of the available options for working with Excel files in PHP, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel).

Comment: already gave that as possible duplicate. still the best list we have on SO ;)

Comment: Sorry Gordon, missed your comment... typical user, wants a __lightweight__ library that does everything :)

Comment: He ended up using Mark's library. Heavy in size but highly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) can generate XLSX files using the technic of templates.

It can also read any sub XML file in the XLSX.

OpenTBS can do the same with any Ms Office (docx, xlsx, pptx) and OpenOffice documents.