# Formatting XLS files with PHP

Tags: php, excel, xls

I'm using [Christian Novak's functions](http://px.sklar.com/code.html/id=488) to generate XLS files with PHP .
It's working very well but i need to format some cells. FOr example i have to bold some titles and expand them.

Is it possible ? How can i do it ?

NOte : i read all related questions

Answer (score 4):

I did once answer this question... actually talking the questioner through the steps involved, but can't find the link to that answer anymore.... it's possible, but only with a pretty major rewrite of Christian's library.... if you need formatting, then you'd be better using one of the alternative libraries that actively supports formatting features such as [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) or any of the alternatives listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel).

Comment: Yes i can use it but actually i want to learn this steps and experience :) Because of this i want to developed it myself. I'll check this alternatives, too. Thank you.

Comment: @Eray - Are you serious about learning the steps? I've spent over six years learning, it really is a major undertaking that's cost me a large part of my life.... If you really want to do so, then the best starting point is to read the MS documentation on the .xls file format (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381461.aspx for the older .xls files; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118.aspx for the newer .xlsx format, or http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf for a vastly simplified .xls overview)....

Comment: ... If you're really serious (after having a look at those links) then volunteer to help me with the ongoing development of PHPExcel

Comment: Someone say "volunteer" and the people run in tears, hehehe

Comment: @Eray - not really a contest.... but if you really are interested in learning, and have the time to spend :) just contact me via the phpexcel forums

Comment: @MarkBaker , i think i don't have 6 years for this :( So, you're right. I'll use one of these classes. But i'm looking them, this classes really large . For example PHPExcel is 17MB. It has a lots of features i know. But i don't need them. I just want to resize columns and bold some cells. Because of this, i'm looking for a simple class still. There are too many classes. Can you suggest me a class ? I will get its functions.

Comment: Never judge a library by the size of the files.... PHPExcel has a lot of comments in the code, and the distribution includes a rather large external library (tcPDF) that I'll be dropping from the distribution at some point, and (if you don't want to generate PDFs) it's safe to delete everything under /Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/PDF/