# Automatic static display of excel spreadsheet in webpage after uploading XLS to the appropriate htdoc directory

Tags: php, html, excel

How about this one. I want to drop my Office 2003 single-sheet workbook into the htdocs folder on my computer and be able to view (but *not* edit) from my browser.

```
<head>
<body>
some fancy text about stuff no one cares about
reference to spreadsheet.xls
<body>
<head>
```

My goal is (a) not to have to upload squat and (b) to have the sheet display, on page, with nice colors and such as it has in Excel. Of the two, (a) is my primary goal.

For thems that care, I do have a nice excel macro that will convert the page to small html, but I dearly wish to avoid doing that manually.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is already in the htdocs directory of your webserver, then you don't have to "upload squat", it's already on the web server.
With a PHP script and one of the Excel reader libraries listed in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) you can read the Excel workbook so that it can be accessed by your script, and you can then iterate over the rows and cells building html markup. 
Personally, I'd recommend using the [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) library, because you can use it to read the file, and to generate html fully formatted with all appropriate syles that you can then echo in the appropriate part of your page.