# Which is the best way to generate excel output in PHP?

Tags: php, excel, cakephp-2.0

Is there any other PHP components like PHPExcel?

Comment: `PHPExcel` is not working well for you?

Comment: PHPExcel is good.But it consumes lots of memory..So i need an alternative

Comment: Alternative might be setting the max_memory_size (or how its called) higher in the pph.ini !

Comment: There is a list here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel - comprising every library of which I'm aware for reading or writing Excel files from PHP.

Comment: What options in PHPExcel have you looked at for conserving memory? Such as cell cacheing?

Comment: You can get output file using php and MySQL. this method is the best way.. http://www.phponwebsites.com/2014/07/php-create-excel-sheet.html

Comment: Another alternative approach that someone could find useful is to use some existing solution for .NET framework from PHP, for example see [this article](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/kb/articles/44-how-to-use-gembox-spreadsheet-in-php).

Comment: 2020 SimpleXLSXGen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is some class that generates PHP Excel files (real excel files, not that .csv thing).
I use **(DEPRICATED)** See edit 2:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

BUT: I have had a problem when trying to read these generated excel files with the java excel READER, so there might be bugs in this PHP script.

1. EDIT: Nice one: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2037-PHP-Generate-spreadsheet-files-Excel-xls-XML-format.html
2. > PhpSpreadsheet is the next version of PHPExcel. It breaks compatibility to dramatically improve the code base quality (namespaces, PSR compliance, use of latest PHP language features, etc.). https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: Ya i agree..Is there any alternative classes like **PHPExcel**.

Comment: Hmm... good point, but in this case the industry standard totally makes sense. Generating .xls(x) is a big thing, due to Excel's very complex structure, so there shouldn't be lots of good script.

Comment: ya thanks...Maybe i should go for PHPExcel...No other choice.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Not giving up yar..But can't wait until they create one..

Answer (score 5):

Some applications generate an HTML table or a CSV file instead of a real Excel file, and pretend it is an Excel file so that Excel opens it. With HTML tables, this works surprisingly well and it even supports some formatting. With the newest Excel versions, however, you get a message asking you whether you really want to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP Excel extension: http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html

Comment: Note that this does require an external (non-PHP) library on the server, and that this is a commercial library