# How to convert html into *.xlsx using php?

Tags: php

Good morning.

I have a test.html file. I would like to convert into test.xlsx using php.
Now, I could create test.xls file using php, whereas it is having only html tags due to that this file could not open directly in excel and it shows extension error. so if the file is having test.xlsx format gets opened smoothly.
I did not know that how to proceed further to get an expected results.
Please help if possible.
Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Balraj

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried to google the search expression: php generate excel? The results would surely get you started.

Comment: Check the help section for how to ask a question, and what types of questions are allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595599/which-is-the-best-way-to-generate-excel-output-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the best way to generate excel output in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595599/which-is-the-best-way-to-generate-excel-output-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPExcel_Reader_HTML function of PHPExcel

Comment: please, add some example.