# Charts, graphs and data export excel in PHP yii

Tags: php, excel, charts, yii-extensions

I generated reports with data and javascript charting library (like highcharts). I am trying to export the reports into excel format with multiple worksheet and excel charts. I can export charting and data as a seperate xls file. I used Yii php framework.

Is it possible to export in a single excel report??

Comment: What options have you looked at, there's a whole load of libraries that produce Excel files, some are even genuine OfficeOpenXML or BIFF files rather than simply html or tsv with a .xls extension

Comment: This response might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel as it lists almost every option for writing Excel workbooks from PHP