# how to generate csv excel sheet using php so that I can use some styling also like font-size and font-color

Tags: php, excel, csv

I want to generate a `CSV` file using `php`. I am able to generate simple `CSV` file but I want to set font-size and font-color dynamically for headings. I found some libraries but those were not upto the mark.

Here is the code by which I can generate simple CSV file

```
$fp = fopen(FCPATH .'assets/' . $filename,'w');
$content = "";

foreach ($query_pairs->result() as $pair) {
    $content .= '<th>' . @$users[$pair->uid1]->name . '</th>' . $sep . ' ' . @$users[$pair->uid2]->name . PHP_EOL;
}

fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

readfile(FCPATH .'assets/' . $filename);
```

Please help

Comment: CSV files by definition do **not** support any kind "styling"

Comment: Why are you preparing an HTML output? Why do you set the content type to `application/vnd.ms-excel` but talking about CSV files? Do you know the differences between the proprietary Excel format and a CSV file?

Comment: @feeela - Doesn't know the the difference between Excel BIFF format and CSV, nor between HTML and CSV.... but it seems a common mistake. Everyone seems to believe in the tooth fairy and in PHP's automagic extension

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that's impossible.

CSV, by definition, only contains data. I'm sorry to bear the bad news, but there will never be a way to do what you're trying to do with CSV.

What you *can* do, with some limits, is export HTML to Excel. This is often done in the absence of Excel libraries.

But for PHP, there are ways to generate Excel files. See for example this:
http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually I want to create CSV file so that when any user open that
file using MS Excel he can see the data with some styling.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid that's impossible, mate. Sorry. CSV cannot contain styling. - Your best bet is then exporting HTML. Excel can render certain HTML styling from HTML tables, and others can open the table in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a real Excel file (BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format, your choice) using one of the [many PHP libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) that can actually generate Excel files rather than simnple HTML markup or CSV masquerading as Excel

Comment: Thanks Mark for providing useful links