# How to save/download the CSV content to Excel

Tags: php, logic, export-to-csv

I have an API, which returns CSV Content as response, I wanted to download at as Excel,
What I tried:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="test_form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" action="http://prime.dev/index.php//data/reporting/downloadCSVFile.json"></form>

<a id="downloadcsv" class="min-button-silver">Download to Excel</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery("#downloadcsv").click(function(e){   
    jQuery('#test_form').submit();  
});
```

**PHP**

```
public function downloadCSVFile()
{
    $data = $this->reporting_service->fetchCSV($request); //API request
    header("Content-Type: application/csv");        
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
    //header("Content-Length: ".$thesize);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    //Will get the response from API like the below;    
    $data = 'clicks|conversions|ctr|cvr|impressions|invalid_clicks|currency.id
    4220894|127984|.1962348497109191647|.0059484688672145487|2150940063|557193|163';
    
    echo $data;
}
```

File is downlaoding as test.csv, but opens in Notepad.

Comment: Excel !== CSV 9regardless of whether the separator is a pipe or a comma. Look at any of the myriad libraries for PHP that can write __actual__ Excel files if you've been told to use xls - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel

Comment: If you want to use CSV instead, the correct mime type is 'text/csv', not 'application/csv'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a download as Excel you need extra software, something like PEAR_Spreadsheet_Excel,
because you have to generate extra headers and many other crap!
But normally if you create a correct CSV-File you can also open it with Excel and it will show all columns seperated like in a normal excel file.