# How to add style when writing text to csv using php

Tags: php, csv

I want to retain the format of my text when I write it into csv.

Example

**First Name** John

**Age** 22

**Country** Afghanistan

On my example I have my label and its value, I want to retain its style when I write it to csv using PHP. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csv` is plain text seperated by commas `,`. There is no styling attached to it. You could all caps the output, or you could use another format that supports text styles.

see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: The easiest/best solution is to use a `php/excel` library. You can find a great list of them at [stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel#3931142](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel#3931142)