# mySQL export to spreadsheet with multiple tabs

Tags: php, mysql, csv, spreadsheet, xls

I have forms inputting to a mySQL backend. Each day I havee a script run that grabs the data from last 24 hours and puts it into a spreadsheet. There are currently 3 tables and 3 spreadsheets created.

I have done this with with:

```
SELECT *
FROM `transfer-authority`
WHERE Time > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 24 HOUR )
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

So it's just a simple CSV. I then use a CRON job to rename this file to the date and email it.

My question is if it is possible to have the results of all **three** tables made into a spreadsheet with a tab per table? I've searched for this but cannot find anything on it.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this was with ssconvert from gnumeric (man page here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ssconvert.1.html).

It was as simple as this bash script after exporting to 3 CSVs:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
ssconvert --merge-to $DATE-chit.xls "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using a CSV, but there are dozens of PHP libraries that allow you to create real Excel files that do support multiple sheets within a workbook. In addition to [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com), this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) on SO lists a good number of libraries capable of doing this

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a vba script to do this in excel. Check http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/543839-combine-csv-files-into-1-excel-workbook-as-sheets.html