# Exporting text with special chars from MySQL/PHP into Excel

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, export

I need to export some data from MySQL database.
Problem is that I have extended latin characters in it, like Š Đ Ć Č Ž and when I do classic export, my words looks like: ÄorÄ‘eviÄ‡ or BoÅ¾iloviÄ‡, and should look like Đorđević / Božilović

Comment: Have you looked at any of the libraries written for PHP that can write Excel data files? In addition to my own http://phpexcel.codeplex.com you'll find a list here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with 1st answer on this question: [Alternative for PHP_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel)

files: http://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data

@Mark Baker- THX!

Comment: In that case, why not credit Eli with an upvote in his answer to that question