# File attachment and read data from file

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a file upload button and a submit button. I want when i upload a excel file from this file upload then data of that excel file should be read and print.
excel file containing-
Name-
Dob-
Number-

i m using this html code-

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post">
<input type="file" name="cir" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What will be php code for print data from excel file i.e.
Name-
Dob-
Number-

Comment: Jan Hančič  am not getting how it'll done on php.

Comment: Have a look at using this library. http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: There's plenty of libraries for reading Excel data in PHP, including my own PHPExcel library - have you looked at any of these?

Comment: @MarkBaker Its not clear on that can u help me here?

Comment: Please identify exactly what help you actually want? I can help with specific problems, but if you simply want somebody to write your code for you then I won't do that.... take a look at some of the libraries for reading Excel files such as PPHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) or those listed in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel to see what they can do