# Fetching data using azax & php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I was doing that when i select a name from combo box then data related to the selected name should be shown from mysql table using ajax. But it could not be done.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser (str)
{
    if(str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=="";
        return;
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmltttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="""showUser(thiis.value)">
<option value="">Select a person</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint">Person List is Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Its shows a notice

Comment: fgetcsv is not for reading images.

Comment: What did you expect using a function to read csv (text files) with an image?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Dear i am not using it for read image.... I have a csv file contains only text.

Comment: `fopen("$cir/$image1", "r");` implies that you are reading an image.

Comment: it looks like browser interpreted binary to me, perhaps $cir/$image1 is the wrong path to your text file.

Comment: @m4t1t0  I am not reading a image.... This is output which shows in browser....

Comment: What does your CSV file contain and in what encoding?

Comment: @deceze it contains text data.

Comment: @dan Lee Its just a variable but i m reading a csv file which contains text....

Comment: *What* text in what encoding? ASCII encoded English? UCS2 encoded Russian? Please be specific.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone its correct path.....Because file is going read but its showing images like above.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're not reading a CSV file, the byte-pattern of the data you show suggests an OLE wrapper containing BIFF data.... ie. it's probably a genuine Excel .xls file. Try opening the file in MS Excel (rename as .xls if necessary) or Gnumeric or Open/Libre Office Calc.

To process the file in PHP, you'll need a PHP library capable of reading Excel xls files: in addition to [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com), you can find a list of other libraries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel).

Comment: If indeed so: good catch. Do you still see the code, or only blondes and brunettes? ;)

Comment: @deceze - A binary stream is indeed a thing of beauty, and you can see patterns in the data... sadly not blondes, brunettes or even redheads.

Comment: The key is in the ÐÏà heading, and in the use of ÿ as a stream padding character

Comment: From your profile I see you have been intimately studying the Office file formats... my hat off to you. And *ÐÏà* is a nice name for a redhead. ;)

Comment: I'll remember it as a name if my nextborn is a redhead :)