# PHP excel exporting package that actually exports BIFF

Tags: php, excel, export, export-to-excel

Does any know of a PHP excel exporting package that satisfies the following conditions:

1. Not PHPExcel - since phpExcel has performance issues with large table
2. Able to export Excel 8.0 - Excel 11.0 (1997-2003) format or later file via PHP such that the file can be downloaded
3. Actually exports in Excel BIFF and not HTML/XML/other tricks

I tried http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/ but it seems to export in an excel version below 8.0 which causes excel 2010 to complain when opening the file

Does anybody know if the PEAR exporter (http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected) satisfy these conditions (obviously it satisfies condition 1)

Comment: Excel 2010 should open old `*.xls` files without the least complaint but I've found it's more restrictive than previous versions when it comes to *corrupted* files (which some libraries generate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find that most Excel exporter classes have performance issues with large tables (including PEAR), and those overheads can be reduced in PHPExcel by using features like cell caching that were deliberately added for just that purpose; but there;'s a whole host of alternatives listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel).