# Is it possible to use javascript for reading an excel file with password protected?

Tags: javascript, php, phpexcel

I have already searched for reading excel file using PHP, I found PHPExcel but it does not support password protected files. Now I am thinking if there is some way on other languages that can be inserted to my PHP codes, like javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find very few libraries that support reading password protected files.... [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) is a list of PHP options for reading Excel files: COM is an option, as is PUNO, and Ilia's extension might handle passwords as well. There's nothing I'm aware of in JavaScript that will help; so your other options are to use another language like Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read it with javascript, since you have to use serverside for that.
if phpexcel doesn't work just google for a library that can read excel documents with password