# Import excel data into mysql using php not the csv format

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Does any body know how to import excel data into mysql using php? not the csv format upload.

Comment: Either save it as CSV in MS Excel, or use one of the many PHP Excel reader libraries (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) to convert it.... but try doing some work yourself; or hire a professional if you want someone to write it for you

Comment: You need to first read that excel file data and then try what u want..add more info

Answer (score 1):

You have to be follow following steps:
1)Upload excel file to server.
2)Write script to read excel file via php file handling tools.
3)Insert read data in appropriate database table.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the excel file into `CSV`, then execute this command,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'yourfullpath.csv' 
INTO TABLE database.table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Other Links:

- [Import Excel Data Into MySQL Using phpMyAdmin](http://www.davalign.com/import-excel-data-into-mysql-using-phpmyadmin.php)

Comment: no csv please ...I want it in the Excel format it self...Thank you