# with php importing excel data into mysql using excelreader2.php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

i have to import a excel data into my mysql database but i facing "**The filename uploads/dd.xlsx is not readable**". I dont know what is error, why my excel sheet is not readable...code of excelreader2.php is.

```
function read($sFileName) {

        $res = $this->_ole->read($sFileName);



        // oops, something goes wrong (Darko Miljanovic)

        if($res === false) {

            // check error code

            if($this->_ole->error == 1) {

                // bad file

                die('The filename ' . $sFileName . ' is not readable');

            }

            // check other error codes here (eg bad fileformat, etc...)

        }

        $this->data = $this->_ole->getWorkBook();

        $this->_parse();

    }
```

i made all the possible checkout....can any one sort out this....

Comment: You have permissions to the file? The file isn't opened in Excel at the same time your app is trying to access it?

Comment: The error says.. "FILE is not readable".. Just change permissions

Comment: what type of permission and how can i change it...???

Comment: Check the file with `bool is_readable ( string $filename )` and try to set the permission with `bool chmod ( string $filename , int $mode )` if the file is not readeable

Comment: i have still the same problem, tried above all suggetions... :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An xlsx file isn't an OLE file. xls files are OLE BIFF files, the standard format until Excel 2003; xlsx files are OfficeOpenXML format, introduced for Excel 2007.

You either need a different library to [read them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel), or a library such as [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) that can read both formats