# Recall parts of an excel file to show on a website

Tags: php, xml, excel, joomla2.5

I've seen this done on quite a few website but just cannot figure it out.
Ive got an excel file with a timetable of prayer times which change each day
this website has it on the top left of the page - http://www.centralmosque.org.uk.
now I have sorted it so that the general universal info is imported via an iframe for some of the info.
the rest in in an excel file and will have 'Jamaat' Times that it will need to extract based on the current date....
Is there a way that I can extract 5 bits of info from an excel file each day and will show on the website as a table...Ican download the excel file so it contains a whole years work of data - but just not sure which software to use to make it happen
Kind Regards
shad

Comment: In Excel, you can create and export an HTML `PublishObject` based on the 5 cells. This becomes an `.htm` file which you could host on your website.

Comment: There's plenty of PHP libraries that can read an Excel file and extract data from it, have you looked at any of them? In addition to my own PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com), there's a load listed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel