# Where can i find a good PHP class to export data from html or dataset to excel file with formating?

Tags: php, excel, class, export-to-excel

I am looking for an existing PHP class that export data to an excel file. I also need to ability to create the design so all the reports will look like the web version of the report.

Can some one please lead me to a good and tested class?

Comment: I could tell you about some PHP libraries that can create Excel files. But I think you have already tried them and regarded them as not suitable. So I won't tell you.

Comment: Aside from my own PHPExcel library (http://www.phpexcel.net and http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) that I'd recommend (as have your other answers), there's a pretty comprehensive list here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export from to Excel format, take a look at  [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try PHPExcel http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ if you haven't. It's pretty good.