# Change font style with fputcsv

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I need to change the text of header from lighter to bold of the csv . I am using fputcsv() of php to generate to csv file.

```
 fputcsv($output,array('Report','Entitlement Report'));
```

This is the basic code which I am using to print the header of my csv file . Any idea to accomplish this or any example

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't achieve this because CSV file doesn't support the font style.

PS: CSV file could be opened with Excel, but it is not Excel file format, doesn't support any style.

Comment: will it support html table?

Comment: @aneesh No, csv file is just about data.

Answer (score 0):

**XLS** / **XLSX** format supports visual styles.
[List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel/3931142#3931142) of libraries for xls reading/writing.

And [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), of course.