# Excel version 2007 is not readable

Tags: php

I'm not able to access Excel in xlsx format using PHP. But I am able to access my data when i save my excel file in xls format. I used the tutorial from the URL below . The same file when i try to make it in xlsx format and it throws an error it's not readable.

I'm use this code from *PHP Drops*: 
http://php-drops.blogspot.in/2011/04/read-excel-sheet-xls-file-with-php.html

Comment: That's because SEW __only__ reads Excel BIFF (xls) file, not OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) files. Try using [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net), which supports both formats, or one of the other PHP libraries for Excel listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this simple parser?

[Simple XLSx PHP Parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6279-PHP-Parse-and-retrieve-data-from-Excel-XLS-files.html)

If it doesn't work, I would suggest contacting the author and see if he is able to come up with a solution to the issue.

PHP Classes is a decent community and lots of developers there are willing to assist.

Best Regards,

EJ