# Prevent Excel from reformatting text in the scientific notation

Tags: php, excel, formatting, excel-2010

I have a PHP script which exports data from database to different formats, including as an Excel document. If a text field contains such a value as `123123123123`, Excel, by default converts it to `1.23123E+11`. Is it possible to prevent this absolutely unnecessary behaviour?

Comment: Can you show the exporting code, please?

Comment: This is off topic because it's about Excel, not programming. Try [su].

Comment: I'm guessing that your "Excel document" is actually a comma-separated value file pretending to be an Excel .xls file... if you're creating a real Excel file, then what library are you using?

Comment: There are thousands of forum threads under the tag `excel`. And besides this question is no less about programming than about excel itself. Because the problem, I guess, can be solved on the part of PHP if I could specifically render values exporting to excel file.

Comment: Then perhaps you'd tell us how you're creating your Excel file

Comment: @Mark Baker Yes, in fact it is not a true Excel file. It's a hand-made file with a number of appropriate headers which pretends to be excel.

Comment: Then perhaps switching to one of the many libraries that can generate real Excel files from PHP scripts will help, because they'll let you set a number format mask for cell values... the list [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) should give you a few options

Comment: I'm not ready to use a library yet, because there is some difficult business logic and on the whole it works well, except this one tiny issue with formatting.

Comment: In that case, try wrapping those longer values in quotes so that they're treated as strings

Comment: @minitech The sript is too large and contains some sort of spaghetti code now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to store the number as text (and not do math on it later) and the PHP is exporting as a CSV, a simple solution would be to export the number as a `CONCATENATE` function.

`=CONCATENATE(123123123123)` renders as `123123123123` in text format when the CSV is opened in Excel (this is for Excel 2010).

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a good solution. But at the same time it is not cross-version - as you say it is for Excel 2010. I found another  solution - to add a space in the front of the number like string. Hope it will work for different versions.

Comment: @Jacobian: Does `="123123123123"` work?

Comment: Yes, it also works. Though an extra space is the simplest way to do things.