# CI Export CSV data formating issue

Tags: php, csv, codeigniter-3

I'm learning PHP & CodeIgniter 3. In this project I need to export some data to a CSV file. I'm able to export the CSV file, however the data is displaying incorrectly in a couple columns. Example (5.32856E+11) where it should be (532856165001). I'm able to see the actual value if you double click the cell.

[image]

Is there anyway to force the data in a CSV to display the data correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Excel from reformatting text in the scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816995/prevent-excel-from-reformatting-text-in-the-scientific-notation)

Comment: Thank you for comment, I will look into PHPSpreadsheet. I was reluctant to use PHPSpreadsheet because it has such a big foot print. I was was hoping CI has something built-in that I not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This is the microsoft excel formatting and does not have any relation with your code just try to regenerate your csv and then re-open your file with a simple text editor (notepad++ or sublim text)