# php excel to mysql. convert xls and xlsx both

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to convert excel to mysql. But I have problems with xls and xlsx. I need a library which supports xls and xlsx together. When I change filename, it should be enough(no change any other code)
For example:

```
something->Open("file.xls");
something->Open("file.xlsx");
```

It should be open these two files.
Is there a library like this and how is that speed.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: So which of the [myriad of libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) have you looked at? Have you looked at [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T think, [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) can help you.