# Insert at word file excel table

Tags: php, html, excel, ms-word

I need to generate Word document using PHP. I have html, save it as doc-file, but now I need to insert in this file excel table. How can I do it with html content, or I need some classes to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent PHP class for creating Excel documents. It is called `php-export-data` by Eli Dickinson, http://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data.

Also you can check this stackoverflow question: [Alternative for PHP_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel/3931142#3931142)

However, this is some sort of advanced task, you better be prepared.

Comment: May be you don't understand me, but I need to create word file with extension .doc and embed at it excel table. You class create a single excel document.