# Reading Excel xlsx files in PHP without ZipArchive class or PHP extension php_zip enabled

Tags: php, excel, nginx, zip, php-extension

I am using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) PHP library for reading xlsx files and every thing is fine.
when I am deploying my web application in our server I am facing the below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'ZipArchive library is not enabled'
```

I know that [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) is a [requirement](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements&referringTitle=Home) for PHP Excel. and I need to follow the install [instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) for it to enable it on my production server.

This error because [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) require the below requirements:

1. PHP version 5.2.0 or higher
2. PHP extension php_zip enabled
3. PHP extension php_xml enabled
4. PHP extension php_gd2 enabled

Now I cant access our [nginx](http://nginx.org/) server and cant compile "PHP extension php_zip" then enable it.

my question is:

Is that any Alternatives for PHP_excel dose not require **ZipArchive class with PHP extension php_zip enabled** ?

I am trying these [Alternatives for PHP_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) but all of them based on zip.so compiled and
php_zip extension enabled.

Any help will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 1.8.0, PHPExcel has offered an alternative built-in Zip handler that can be enabled by setting

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

before loading any files that are zip-based archives such as xlsx or ods

This is slower and uses more memory than PHP's own ZipArchive extension, but provides an alternative if ZipArchive isn't enabled

Comment: thanks for reply but , using this option dose not mean no PHP extension php_zip required it's another option based on same extension you can test 
 PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
                    die(var_dump(PHPExcel_Settings::getZipClass()));  return PHPExcel_Shared_ZipArchive .. also based on that extension any ideas

Comment: The PCLZIP code is __not__ based on the ZipArchive extension in any way; it replicates the core functionality of ZipArchive with its own pure PHP code... ZipArchive is __not__ required to use the PCLZip option, otherwise there would be no point in even having the PCLZip option

Comment: YA really thank you so so much you are totally right the above comment was on older version not the one you suggest thank a lot (y)

Comment: for ubuntu 14.04 and php5.5, apt-get install php5.5-zip php5.5-xml