# mysqli export to xls issue

Tags: php, mysqli, export, xls

I have troble geting this work and I can't figure it out what is the issue.
I download a xls file, but it doesent opens.
I had a mysql script like this, working, and I tried to convert it into mysqli and probably something is wrong... 
Thanks in advance

```
$sqlExp = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $countQryExp  = mysqli_query($link, $sqlExp );
  $filename = "sampledata.xls"; // File Name

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$flag = false;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($countQryExp,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly the problem is?

Comment: If you're generating a csv file (whether you believe that's an Excel file or not) then use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function rather than trying to write the same functionality (badly) yourself

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more to generating an Excel file than giving it a content type of `application/vnd.ms-excel`. Excel is a very particular format, whereas you're generating a TSV file - tab separated values, and in a pretty breakable manner (what happens if someone puts a `\t` in one of your site's fields, or a new line?).

If you want to generate real Excel files, you'll want [one of the various libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) for doing so. If a CSV/TSV are fine, just export a `.csv`/`.tsv` file with proper headers.

Comment: I agree. My favorite is PHPExcel