# Exporting xlsx in php without using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

It seems to me that the phpexcel library can be a bit slow (and memory intensive) when creating xlsx files of significant size. Is there a better standardized solution I should be using? Everyone I know uses phpexcel.

Comment: If its just data you are creating then you can use a CSV, but if you are exporting formatting and calculations etc you cannot beat phpExcel

Comment: [Alternatives to PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel/3931142#3931142)