# Export database data to excel using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm trying to get my MySQL data to Excel file using php. The codes work fine but I want the field name to look like this

[image]

and not simply this

[image].

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
    include_once('config.php');

   $xls_filename = 'export_'.date('Y-m-d').'.xls'; 

     $result = mysql_query("Select * from ojt_group3_pole"); 

   header("Content-Type: application/xls"); 
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_filename"); 
   header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
   header("Expires: 0"); 

   $sep = "\t"; 


   for ($i = 0; $i<mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) { 
    echo mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "\t"; 
   } 
   print("\n"); 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
   { 
     $schema_insert = ""; 
     for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result); $j++) 
     { 
       if(!isset($row[$j])) { 
        $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep; 
       } 
       elseif ($row[$j] != "") { 
         $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep; 
       } 
       else { 
         $schema_insert .= "".$sep; 
      } 
     } 
     $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert); 
     $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert); 
     $schema_insert .= "\t"; 
     print(trim($schema_insert)); 
     print "\n"; 
   } 
?>
```

Comment: stop using mysql_*

Comment: First, make sure you stop using "mysql_" functions. They're deprecated and completely removed in newer versions of PHP. You should use either mysqli_ functions or PDO.

Comment: your not writing excel formated data, but plain text

Comment: A quick and dirty solution you could try is to create the format you want using ordinary HTML tables. Just remove the headers while building it. When it looks correct in the browser, add the headers back and it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is basically generating a CSV file and giving it a ".xls" extension and expecting Excel to do the work of correcting the problem when the file is opened.

The CSV format does **not** support all the features that Excel has, so things like cell merging and styles are not going to be something you can do with your current approach.

You'll have to use a library like PHPExcel (there are likely others, too) to generate true Excel files and then write the code to do things like mergeCells() to set up the spreadsheet the way you want it to look. A very basic example:

```
<?php
// Load the libraries
include 'PHPExcel.php';
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

// Create a new PHPExcel instance
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set the workbook properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Your name here");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("My Excel Document");

// Add data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:B1');

// Save the file
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save("mynewfile.xlsx");
```

EDIT: As someone pointed out, PHPExcel is deprecated. There's a question here on SO that lists out some alternatives:
[Alternative for PHP_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel)

The underlying point here, though, is that if you want to make use of Excel's formatting features, you'll have to generate a true Excel document.

Comment: PhpExcel is deprecated

Comment: "PhpExcel is deprecated"  says? @SailorJ

Comment: Is there other way aside from using PHPExcel?

Comment: @rtfm - Their own github repo: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel : The title of it _"PHPExcel - DEPRECATED"_

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, ta.

Comment: @Katherine open an excel file in a text editor - its not text.

Comment: The newer xlsx formats (and other Office formats ending in "x") are actually ZIP files containing a specific structure and a bunch of cross-referenced XML files and resource files.